# Having Issues with set td width in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

So, I've tried a lot of solutions, but can't figure out why the td width isn't displaying properly in Outlook 2010, when I send an HTML email. I have copied and pasted the code below; any takers on why this isn't working?

```
    <html><head><style type="text/css">

    body {
        background-position: top center;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: "Century Gothic", Times, serif;    

    }

    a {
        color: #25354f;
        font-weight:bold;

    }

    table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-spacing:0; 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding:0px;
        cellspacing:0;
        cellpadding:0;
        border:0;
    }

    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    td.header {
        font-family: "Century Gothic", Times, serif;
        font-size:20pt;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-align:right;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding:10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        top:0px!important;
        margin-top:0px!important;
        margin:0;

    }

    th.logo {
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding:10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        top:0px!important;
        margin-top:0px!important;
        margin:0;

    }

th.divide {
    background-color:#000000;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Times, serif;
    font-size:.1pt;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:left;
}

th.body {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Times, serif;
    font-size:11pt;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:left;
    padding:20px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    top:0px!important;
    margin-top:0px!important;
    margin:0;

}

td.signature1 {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Times, serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    color:#999999;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:center;
    padding:0px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
}

td.signature2 {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Times, serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    color:#999999;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
}


</style></head><body>
<center>
<table width="700">
<tr><td width ="290">&nbsp;</td>

<td width="410">&nbsp;</td></tr>




<tr><th colspan="2" class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></th></tr>

<tr><th colspan="2" class="divide">&nbsp;</th></tr>

<tr><th colspan="2" class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et libero vitae nunc cursus iaculis ut in risus. Maecenas libero felis, aliquam eu fermentum eu, posuere eu nibh. Vestibulum in leo semper, scelerisque nisi sit amet, egestas nisl. Vestibulum et convallis tellus. Donec id est eget elit blandit feugiat. Sed ullamcorper magna justo, a commodo erat dapibus a. Suspendisse vitae ipsum et nunc aliquet scelerisque at et massa.
<br><br>
Donec mollis elit purus, vel dignissim dui ultricies a. Nunc tincidunt magna quis rhoncus mattis. Nam sed luctus purus, varius lacinia nunc. Etiam id lacus pellentesque enim volutpat aliquam a eu felis. Quisque lectus enim, volutpat sed dapibus vel, aliquam a sem. Integer faucibus turpis nisl, vel porta lectus sollicitudin sit amet. Sed laoreet, massa eu eleifend ultrices, metus mauris porta sem, at porta libero purus et ligula. Vestibulum a mi consequat enim dignissim elementum. Vestibulum eu ligula et tortor placerat elementum. Fusce molestie ipsum ac eros commodo fringilla. Suspendisse nec ipsum tortor. Curabitur sem nibh, elementum nec ligula vel, ullamcorper vestibulum tortor. Duis nec magna congue risus blandit luctus eget at quam.
<br><br>
Best,<br>
Operations
<br>

</th></tr>


<tr><th colspan="2" class="divide">&nbsp;</th></tr>


<tr><td width="290"><a href="[twitter url]"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RJzaFLl.png"></a> &nbsp;

    <a href="[linkedinurl]"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PE8QtpN.png"></a> &nbsp;
    <a href="[company website]><img src="[company tag]"></a></td>

<td width="410">

        <font face="Arial"><font size=2 color="#0000ff"><b>Your Name Goes Here</b></font> <font size=1 color="#000000">| Your Title Goes Here | Company</font> 

        <br>

        <font size=1 color="#000000">Your office address</font>

        <br>

        <font size=1 color="#000000">D:  000.000.0000 | F: 000.000.0000</font>

        <br>

        <font size=1 color="#000000">E:  <a href="mailto:email">email@email.com</a> &nbsp; </font>

        <br>

        <font size=1 color="#000000">Alternate Point of Contact:  <a href="mailto:altcontact@email.com">altcontact@email.com</a> | 000.000.0000</font></font></td></tr>


<tr><th colspan="2" class="divide">&nbsp;</td></tr>

</table><br>

<a name="Hyperlink_20150914_130015975" xt="SPONECLICKOPTOUT" href="#SPONECLICKOPTOUT" target="_blank"> <font size=1>Click here to opt out of these alert emails.</a>
</center>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Which TD is displaying wrong?

Comment: In this Email on Acid test, they look the same in Outlook 2010, 2007, Thunderbird, etc. https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/r5N962ygoqmKt37I4EYtJCIVGQmMngih1YB1JeWtjIdrh/shared

Comment: The td at the very bottom (signature line) is displaying weirdly.

Comment: As far as I can tell, its width is consistent across all clients.

Comment: But it's not when I actually send it to outlook; that's the problem I'm having.

Comment: For anyone who has this same issue in the future, I was able to get it to display properly by using percentages to set the width - weird, but it worked.